# Web page causes switch from Quirks to IE 9 Standards mode - HTML1113

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I have two HTML pages.

Onload page 1 produces no messages..however when I login and page 2 is displayed, I get  a message from IE9 saying that

```
HTML Quirks to IE 9 Standards....HTML1113
```

How do I begin to troubleshoot this?  I would like both pages to interpret as IE 9 Standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the DTDs are not the same.  If you use a strict DOCTYPE like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

IE9 will use standards mode

Comment: That would do it. If its, not a valid type you get quirks, which is the default for "backward compatibility".